# How To Checkout Aptoide Source code

Tags: android, svn, app-store, svn-checkout

I need to checkout aptoide source code from [here](http://dev.aptoide.org/browser/aptoide-client/4.2.4.1). I have tried to checkout the source code by using TortoiseSVN in Windows platform and get the following error.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem. I have downloaded [RapidSVN](http://www.rapidsvn.org/download/nightly/win32/) and fetched the repository from [this link](http://aptoide.org/repo/aptoide-client/4.2.4.1)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a temporary glitch on the server side. You can notify [Aptitode devs](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/aptoide-dev) about the error.